# Use same children under two different parents in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have 2 different ways to access some pages, a view mode and an edit mode. so I would like to have the following two URLs for those options (all the pages are quals, they will be handled by a parameter - edit or not):

`profile/first-tab/1` (for viewing)

`profile/first-tab/edit/1` (for editing)

The profile is the parent, and beneath that are 5 children (first-tab, second-tab...)

How do I configure routing for that the best way?

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your routing like this and have the same component for both routes

```
 const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'profile/first-tab/1', component: SomeComponent },
  { path: 'profile/first-tab/edit/1', component: SomeComponent }
];
```

Comment: Thanks ! What about the children, shall I implement those under each parent, or can I implement then once?

Comment: you can have the edit option like as queryparam.
otherwise yes you need to have the children for each parent.